# Vue prevent page rendering until auth validated

Tags: validation, authentication, vuejs2, page-lifecycle

I've got a long-standing vue application that uses 3rd party login for people to authenticate. An issue that we need to fix is that when a user hits a given page via a link, the page briefly displays in a half-rendered state before the user gets redirected to the 3rd party to authenticate. The 'container' rendering is ok, but not the main content of the page. I can move the auth check code to earlier parts of the life-cycle, but the flicker never quite goes away.

Is there an idiomatic way in Vue to prevent the main content of a page from rendering until some other validation (e.g. auth creds) has finished? Is there a standard flow for auth and auth redirects in particular?

Comment: If you haven't tried it, I would suggest validating auth via a [nav guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html), provided you're using `vue-router`. I would also suggest wrapping the 'secret' component with a parent component and validating auth on the parent component using `beforeEnter`.

Comment: We are using vue-router, this seems to be pretty much perfect. Please write this as an answer and I'll at least upvote it!

Comment: @glitch your solution worked perfectly - please rewrite as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't tried it, I would suggest validating auth via a [nav guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html), provided you're using vue-router. I would also suggest wrapping the 'secret' component with a parent component and validating auth on the parent component using `beforeEnter`